# Finding the formula for the expected value for an event with multiple trials and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

(Sorry if the question is badly titled, I had a hard time to find a concise yet correct way of expressing the situation I'm in)

Hello,

Let's say I have a game in which I must roll a value between 1 and 100 (inclusive).
If I roll 75 or less, I have a gain of 25; and I roll again the value with the same threshold to win the gain. I can go up to 3 rolls for a total maximum gain of 75.
If I roll more than 75, I gain nothing more (but I keep what I earned with the precedent rolls) and can't roll anymore.
Each roll is  equally probable

I would like to compute the expected value of such a game, and my problem is that I have the method of doing this manually, but not the formula

In this game, there are 4 outcomes possibles

| 1st roll | 2nd roll | 3rd roll |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S | S | S |
| S | S | F |
| S | F | F |
| F | F | F |

For each roll, probabilities are as the following

| 1st roll | 2nd roll | 3rd roll | P(outcome) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75% | 75% | 75% | 42% |
| 75% | 75% | 25% | 14% |
| 75% | 25% | 100% | 19% |
| 25% | 100% | 100% | 25% |

I assumed that, since you can't roll again if you fail, we could say that your subsequent probability of failing for the next roll is 100%

Since I have the probability and the gain of every outcome, I can thus compute the expected value, which should be (I if made no mistake), about 43.36 ($\frac{P(outcome_1)\times75 + P(outcome_2)\times50 + P(outcome_3)\times25 + P(outcome_4)\times0}{\sum_{i=1}^nP(outcome_n)}$)

With all that said, what I would like is to find the formula allowing me to compute the expected value from the initial data, rather than having to pass through all theses intermediate steps

Thanks,
Meta

Comment: The rules are not clear.  You say what happens if you throw $≤75$, but what happens if you throw $>75$?  Your table makes it appear that such a roll ends the game, but that should be specified.  Also, is each roll equally probable?

Comment: Should add:  I don't see anything wrong with the computation you performed.   Since the payout is path dependent, I wouldn't expect anything much more efficient.  You can simplify the problem statement by just saying each trial has a $\frac 34$ chance of success (the bit about the $75$ doesn't change anything).

Comment: @lulu : Yes I edited my initial message to clarify the rules but you where right. And each roll is equally probable
(I chose to keep 75% and cie. since I find it to be more telling that fractions in this case)

Comment: You can use the formula $p^n \times n \times s + \sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} p^i \times q \times i \times s$ where $p$ is probability of win in each round, $n$ is number of rounds, $q = 1 - p$, $s$ is sum that you can win in each round.

Comment: As mentioned above, the game outcome depends on the number of rolls until the first failure. So it is like a truncated geometric random variable.

Comment: @MathLover I like this formula a lot for it is very generic.
It's off-topic, but that makes me wonder about the general formula for calculating the expected value. The standard one taught in school is $E(X) = \sum_{i=0}^nx_ip_i$ but it seems to me that the formula you gave can't be factored to be like the standard one. And that's normal since these are two different situations. But that also means that there is a more generic formula from which the standard one and the one specific to this type of problem derive. And I just find it very interesting to try to learn what it is like.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p = 3/4, q = 1 - p.$

Chance of return of $0 = q.$

Chance of return of $25 = pq.$

Chance of return of $50 = p^2q.$

Chance of return of $75 = p^3.$

Overall computation is

$$q(0 + 25p + 50p^2) + 75p^3.$$

Comment: I find this formula to be very elegent, and, furthermore, it works
Thank you